# Get top n records with grouped table

Tags: mysql

I have an order table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      created_at     |     user_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-14 01:01:59 |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-14 02:01:59 |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-13 00:01:59 |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-14 03:01:59 |       3          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-12 23:01:59 |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-12 23:01:59 |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-10 14:01:59 |       3          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-11 20:01:59 |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-09 12:01:59 |       3          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I grouped my table by this query to get top newest order each user:

```
select created_at, user_id
from orders
order by user_id, created_at desc
```

I got these records:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      created_at     |     user_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-14 01:01:59 |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-13 00:01:59 |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-12 23:01:59 |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-14 02:01:59 |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-12 23:01:59 |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-11 20:01:59 |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-14 03:01:59 |       3          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-10 14:01:59 |       3          |
|---------------------|------------------|
| 2019-10-09 12:01:59 |       3          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Now I want it return only 2 first records each group. How I can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using **mysql 8.0** or higher you can use `row_number() over partition by..`

```
select t1.created_at, t1.user_id from (
select row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at desc) rn, created_at, user_id
from orders) t1 where t1.rn <=2
```

using **mysql versions 5.7** and below

```
SELECT t1.created_at, t1.user_id 
FROM (SELECT 
      @row_number:=CASE
          WHEN @varId = user_id 
            THEN 
                @row_number + 1
            ELSE 
                 1
          END AS rn,
      @varId:=iuser_id user_id,
      created_at
    FROM
        orders,
        (SELECT @varId:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
    ORDER BY 
        user_id asc, created_at desc) t1 
WHERE t1.rn <= 2
```

Comment: I got error Unknown column 't1.rn' in 'where clause'

Comment: updated. try again

Comment: Sorry for annoying but anyway for me to do the same like this in MySQL 5.7

Comment: it's only give my 2 first row of whole result. Not same like your row_number() query sir.

Comment: try above query for 5.7